# Music app is stuck forever on Loading Cloud Music Library

Tags: itunes, music, itunes-match

I subscribed to iTunes Match, but either Music or iTunes got stuck forever on loading.

If I remember correctly, in this Apple/iCloud account, I had a lot of music on Match (around ~2000).

What can I do?

I'm willing to lose my previous collection if I can use the service.

[image: Music app]

Comment: Try quitting the Music app, then log out of your Apple ID, then log back in.

Comment: I did. I've closed the Music app, logged out my Apple ID, and logged back. No luck, unfortunately.